# How to massage data before redirect to another web application in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core-2.0

Is there a way to capture a request before redirect to parent app from virtual app. My parent app is in .net framework 4.0 and virtual app in .net core 2.0
I am trying to find a way by which I want to modify some data in virtual app before redirect to parent app. The redirection is possible through URL in menu which is built dynamically. 
 So to summarize, when user is in virtual app and when they click any menu link that request should be captured in .net core 2.0 app where I would like to do some data modification(eg: cookie) and then allow redirection. Thanks!

> EDIT

One way is to change all the menu links in my virtual app to a common controller and then based on whether a redirect to parent app is  requested I can achieve my result (by doing some checking in that new common controller method) but then I am talking about more than 800 menu links.

Comment: Can you clarify on what you mean by "virtual app"?

Comment: Its a child web application application. Eg: Parent application can be accessed via URL: localhost/MyApp and virtual app is something like localhost/MyApp/MySubApp

Answer (score 0):

The concept of virtual sub-app is only valid in the webserver, that hosts the sites (eg. IIS) The two web applications have no knowledge of each other. Therefore the only tool available for you is a standard HTTP redirect.

You can set any parameters in the query string for the HTTP 301/302 redirect, but unfortunately *you cannot set a cookie on a redirect*.

Alternatively you can return a standard HTML response - there you change cookies - and then let the response contain a META tag for redirect like this:

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://yourdomain.com/mainsite/'" />
```